# jQuery animation to go back to normal

Tags: jquery, animation, css-animations

I am trying to animate all these div, depending on which one is selected

My problem is that I would like all of them to go in the middle, as the first one (.black.1)

So for instance if it is .black.2, again the animation to go in the middle of the table div and so on for all the other ones

Not sure how to calculate the positions

My js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var divWidth = $('.black').width();
        var divHeight = $('.black').height();
        var $this = $('.table');
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var width = $this.width();
        var height = $this.height();     
        var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
        var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;    

        animation = function() {
            $('.black.1').animate({
                height: "150%",
                width: "150%",
                top: centerY - 2 * divHeight,
                left: centerX - 3 * divWidth
            });
        }
        animation();
    console.log (centerX, centerY, divWidth, divHeight);
});
```

Also can't figure out how to return black div animation to its normal position after few seconds

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/58fuzph2/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var center = $(".black.5")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var animation = function animation(args) {
        // initial position settings
        var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect()
        , settings = {}, reset = {};
        for (var prop in center) {
            if (prop !== "width" && prop !== "height") {
                var props = center[prop] - (pos[prop] + 2.5);
                // initial animate settings
                settings[prop] = props;
                // return to initial position settings,
                // after 750ms delay                    
                reset[prop] = "-=" + props;
            } else {
                settings[prop] = "+=25";
                reset[prop] = "-=25";
            }
        };
        settings.margin = -5;
        reset.margin = 5;
        return $(this).animate(settings, 1500, "linear")
        .delay(750).animate(reset, 1500, "linear");
    };

    $(".black").not(".5").on("click", function () {
        animation.call(this);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).trigger("click")
    });
  
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.table {
    width:200px;
    height:160px;
}
ul > li {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.black {
    background:black;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="table">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="black 1"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 2"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 3"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 4"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 5"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 6"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 7"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 8"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="black 9"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dikei Tried `js` at post ?